# How to preserve row order when saving data frame in ms access

Tags: r

I have the following data frame `df1`. I am trying to save this in MS access table `df1`using `sqlSave`. It saves the data in the table but the row order is not preserved. I cant seem to figure out why

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 a   b   c
 2   4   1
 3   3   12
 5   3   2")

library(RODBC)
db <- "Z:/test.accdb"
con2 <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
sqlSave(con2,df1 ,"df1",rownames=FALSE)
```

Table `df1` in ms access looks like this

```
df1     
a   b   c
5   3   2
2   4   1
3   3   12
```

Comment: You could add a field for row order if it is important

Comment: guessing from the documentation, `fast = FALSE` maybe?